# Protrusion of superscripts/cites

Tags: microtype

### Problem

I'm currently using the `microtype` package which allows for some protrusion of certain characters into the margin, and works well for the most part during typical use. But I have been playing around with it and found that for superscripts, the `microtype` package seems to give too much leeway, leading to really ugly protrusions. See the MWE:

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip = half*]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{libertine}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage[super]{cite}

% Not really 'essential' but your code should take this into account
% Also for easier demonstration of the problem
\newcommand\mcite[1]{\,$^[$\mcitehelp#1&\relax$^]$} 
\let\svcite\cite 
\def\mcitehelp#1&#2\relax{%
    \svcite{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax%
    \else$^,$\mcitehelp#2\relax\fi%
}
\let\cite\mcite

% References
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
    @article{testref1,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref2,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref3,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref4,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref5,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Citing and Bibliography test}
Single citations test\cite{testref1}. Multi citations test\cite{testref2,testref3}.
Protrusion is hard to test some words longgggg\mcite{testref1&testref2&testref3&testref4, testref5}.

\lipsum[1] % To see the protrusion more clearly

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

And the output is as such:
[image]

Notice the normal protrusions in the lipsum text, and the protrusion of the superscripted references.

### Question

How do I set a similar protrusion limit for superscripted text, especially considering the fact that I enclose my cites in square brackets?

Comment: Superscript citation style is *evil*! `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with `microtype`, per se.  Rather, the TeX paragraph forming algorithm is just having a tough go of it.  There are three options I see, though each of them has drawbacks:

1. Redefine `\mcitehelp` to include `\allowbreak` to allow linebreaking mid reference;
2. Employ `sloppypar` for the paragraph in question; or
3. Rewrite the paragraph to avoid the condition to begin with.

Here is the MWE, showing the first two approaches.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip = half*]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{libertine}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage[super]{cite}

% Not really 'essential' but your code should take this into account
% Also for easier demonstration of the problem
\newcommand\mcite[1]{\,$^[$\mcitehelp#1&\relax$^]$} 
\let\svcite\cite 
\def\mcitehelp#1&#2\relax{%
    \svcite{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax%
    \else$^,\allowbreak$\mcitehelp#2\relax\fi%
}
\let\cite\mcite

% References
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
    @article{testref1,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref2,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref3,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref4,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref5,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Citing and Bibliography test}

Single citations test\cite{testref1}. Multi citations test\cite{testref2,testref3}.
Protrusion is hard to test some words longgggg\mcite{testref1&testref2&testref3&testref4, testref5}.

\begin{sloppypar}
Single citations test\cite{testref1}. Multi citations test\cite{testref2,testref3}.
Protrusion is hard to test some words longgggg\mcite{testref1&testref2&testref3&testref4, testref5}.
\end{sloppypar}

\lipsum[1] % To see the protrusion more clearly

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm not particularly sure which is more acceptable, typography-wise, so I decided to ask here to see if anyone else has a better idea. So far option 2 seems to be the more aesthetically pleasing one (save for option 3). I'll wait to see if there are any others who may have thoughts on this matter before I accept an answer. Thanks for your input!